# error: Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)

Tags: centos6

I want to install sphinx on Centos 6.4 but i get errors.
What can i do so i can install sphinx? I have searcged around but can only find i need to reinstall mysql (yeah, that is not what i'm looking for. Also reinstalling the VPS is not a good solution ;-))

```
    [root@server01 src]# yum install --nogpgcheck sphinx-2.1.5-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
---------------------
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: sphinx-2.1.5-1.rhel6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
**Error: Package: sphinx-2.1.5-1.rhel6.x86_64 (/sphinx-2.1.5-1.rhel6.x86_64)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: sphinx-2.1.5-1.rhel6.x86_64 (/sphinx-2.1.5-1.rhel6.x86_64)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)**
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to install the MySQL compat package which will provide libmysqlclient.so.16

Go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and change the platform selector to RedHat Enterprise Linux and look for the "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 / Oracle Linux 6 (x86, 64-bit), RPM Package
Compatibility Libraries"

Once you install that, you can then install Sphinx.